# General Failure when opening a link in Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

Why do I get the below error whenever I click on a link in a message in Outlook 2007?

```
General Failure. The application cannot be found.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Control Panel > Internet Options > Advanced > Reset Internet Explorer Settings > Reset... > Reset

Comment: But this might change things that one wants to remain the same.

Comment: At least make sure that you have a 'Default' browser set