# Outlook 10 error: General failure. The URL was: Application not found

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, links

I am using Outlook 10 and it was opening hyperlinks in Firefox. I uninstalled Firefox and installed Chrome. From Chrome->settings I have set up it as default web browser. The problem is that now Outlook cant open any hyperlinks from outlook messages.

```
General failure. The URL was: Application not found.
```

Seems like it tries to open link in Firefox. How this can be fixed?

I tried this [General Failure when opening a link in Outlook 2007](https://superuser.com/questions/72594/general-failure-when-opening-a-link-in-outlook-2007) but it doesn't help

Comment: Go to Control Panel -> Default Programs -> Associate a file type or protocol, scroll down and check the handler for .htm and .html.

Comment: I set it to Google chrome but it doesn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I was you, I'll also remove all browsers, reset to the mighty IE and try to open links alone... if that works, then Chrome might be the issue, reinstalling it maybe.. using ccleaner to remove it thoroughly. befroe even trying the bandaid fix below

this could be what you looking for?

```
HKEY_Current_User, Software, Classes
```

the entries should look like `ChromeHTML` or `FirefoxHTML`

source: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310049

Comment: Re-installing Chrome helped

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in Outlook 2013 and eventually figured out a fix which you might want to try out and see if it works.

If IE was set as the default browser then all was fine, but as soon as you made Chrome the default browser the application not found error appears.

Firstly, I noticed that Google Chrome wasn't listed in Default Programs (Start - Default Programs - Set Default Programs) which was odd and explained why Outlook wasn't able to tell Chrome to open a URL in an email.

Go into the registry and take a look at HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML\shell\open\command. Does it have a string key in there of type REG_SZ and the value is "c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome-original.exe" -- "%1". If so, you'll find that this application doesn't actually exist. Change the key to "c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -- "%1".

You should now find that Chrome is listed in default programs and can be selected as the default browser. The links should now work.